# TikZ: Problem in overlaying a bar plot to existing bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created a normalized histogram by the following code using tikzpicture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    ybar interval,
    x tick label as interval=false,
    xlabel = {$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot{\bf u}_{int}$},
    xtick={},
    xtickten={-18,-16,...,4},
    yticklabels={$0.0001\%$, $0.001\%$, $0.01\%$, $0.1\%$, $1\%$, $10\%$, $100\%$},
    xmin=1e-17, xmax=1e+4,
    ymin=1e-5,ymax=1,
    grid=none,
    ymajorgrids,
]
\addplot [fill=gray!90] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
Lower Upper Count
9.9e-15 1e-14      0.1231
1e-14   1e-13      1e-15
1e-13   1e-12      0.0000
1e-12   1e-11      0.0000
1e-11   1e-10      0.0000
1e-10   1e-9       0.0000
1e-9    1e-8       0.0000
1e-8    1e-7       0.0001
1e-7    1e-6       0.0001
1e-6    1e-5       0.0004
1e-5    1e-4       0.0010
1e-4    1e-3       0.0048
1e-3    1e-2       0.0313
1e-2    1e-1       0.1562
1e-1    1e+0       0.3464
1e+0    1e+1       0.2684
1e+1    1e+2       0.0645
1e+2    1e+3       0.0036
1e+3    1e+4       1e-15
};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This will create a figure like the following:
[image]

I have tried to overlay another histogram to the figure by adding the following code.

```
\addplot [fill=gray!50] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
Lower Upper Count
1e-16 1e-15 1
};
```

Unfortunately, after adding the above code I will end up having the following figure.
[image]

I only want to overlay the second dataset to the existing histogram without introducing any gap between the bars. A figure similar to the following where the red bar represents the second dataset (this figure is made by myself in Photoshop not by TikZ): [image]

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: The MWE is firstly incomplete as you do not state which version of `pgfplots` is used and also I was not able to generate the first plot using the code provided (`compat=1.7`).

Comment: I don't know how to find the version. But I was able to find the date for the package, which is 2010-08-09. Does this help?

Comment: Put `\listfiles` in your preamble and look at the version of `pgfplots` in the `.log` file. But I can say that you have a very old version. I suggest that you update it.

Comment: @Ahmad It is recommended practice for `pgfplots` to use `\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` where 1.7 is the version number. Your installation sounds very old. Please update. You can also look the accompanying `pgfplots` manual which will clearly state the version you are using. Also, the MWE should be something which a person can compile without any modification. Something like the answer provided by Jake to your earlier question including documentclass, packages and `\begin{document}` statements.

Comment: I used \listfiles and the version I am using is 1.4.1. I am going to update it.

Comment: I have now pgfplots 2012/10/26 v1.7 Data Visualization (1.7-2-ge24fff4).

Comment: Unfortunately, after updating all the bars in the figures in the question are upside down.

Comment: I fixed the problem of upside-down by adding `log origin=infty`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. You will get used to it after a while. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have several `ybar interval`s in the same axis, you need to provide the `ybar interval` keyword to the individual `\addplot` commands, otherwise PGFPlots will introduce a shift between the bars to make sure both plots are visible.

Also note that the `ybar interval` style does not use the values you provide in the `Upper` column to determine how wide the bars should be, but instead it uses two consecutive `Lower` values. That means that you always need to provide an extra data row at the end of your table to determine how wide the last bar should be:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    x tick label as interval=false,
    xtick={},
    xtickten={-18,-16,...,4},
    yticklabels={$0.0001\%$, $0.001\%$, $0.01\%$, $0.1\%$, $1\%$, $10\%$, $100\%$},
    xmin=1e-17, xmax=1e+4,
    ymin=1e-5,ymax=1,
    grid=none,
    ymajorgrids,
    log origin=infty,
    bar shift=0pt
]
\addplot [fill=gray!90,
    ybar interval] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
Lower Upper Count
9.9e-15 1e-14      0.1231
1e-14   1e-13      1e-15
1e-13   1e-12      0.0000
1e-12   1e-11      0.0000
1e-11   1e-10      0.0000
1e-10   1e-9       0.0000
1e-9    1e-8       0.0000
1e-8    1e-7       0.0001
1e-7    1e-6       0.0001
1e-6    1e-5       0.0004
1e-5    1e-4       0.0010
1e-4    1e-3       0.0048
1e-3    1e-2       0.0313
1e-2    1e-1       0.1562
1e-1    1e+0       0.3464
1e+0    1e+1       0.2684
1e+1    1e+2       0.0645
1e+2    1e+3       0.0036
1e+3    1e+4       1e-15
};    
\addplot [fill=red!50, ybar interval] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
Lower Count
1e-16 1
1e-15 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```